# Вылетает программа при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

У меня есть метод `void MyOnclick(View v)` при нажатии на кнопку вылетает программа лог вылета

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method MyOnclick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'Bt_reg'
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:6013)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5970)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Я пытался инициализировать методом `setOnClickListener` Тоже вылетает с такой же ошибкой. Пробовал в xml файле удалять `android:onClick` та же самая ошибка. Как это исправить?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.example.kursuir.models.User;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int splash = 3000;
Button reg,log;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference users;
RelativeLayout root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        reg = findViewById(R.id.Bt_reg);
        log = findViewById(R.id.Bt_log);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("users");


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            },splash);
        }

    public void MyOnclick(View v) {
        showRegisterWindow();
    }

    public void showRegisterWindow() {
        root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialog.setTitle("Register");
                dialog.setMessage("Put all data");
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View register_window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sing_up_window, null);
        dialog.setView(register_window);

        MaterialEditText login = register_window.findViewById(R.id.LoginText);
        MaterialEditText pass = register_window.findViewById(R.id.PassText);
        MaterialEditText passconf = register_window.findViewById(R.id.ConfPassText);

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Register", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(login.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root,"Enter your login", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(pass.getText().toString().length() < 8) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Enter your Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(passconf.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Enter your Password again", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                //регистрация
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(login.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                User user = new User();
                                user.setLogin(login.getText().toString());
                                user.setLogin(pass.getText().toString());

                                users.child(user.getLogin())
                                        .setValue(user)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        Snackbar.make(root,"Register sucsesful",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

MainActivity's layout:

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
android:id="@+id/Bt_log"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Login" 

androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
android:id="@+id/Bt_reg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:onClick="MyOnclick"
 android:text="Register"
```

Comment: Самое простое решение - не назначать слушатель в разметке, но назначать его программно

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: reg.setOnClickListener(v -> showRegisterWindow());

Comment: А ещё возможно причина в двух setContentView(), попробуйте убрать вот эту строку:  ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);```